# vagrant fails to create box with libvirt

Tags: linux, linux-kvm, qemu, vagrant

I am trying to setup a box with vagrant and libvirt with the following Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define :test_vm do |test_vm|
    test_vm.vm.box = "test"
    test_vm.vm.network :private_network, :ip => '10.20.30.40'
  end

  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
    libvirt.driver = "qemu"
    libvirt.host = "localhost"
    libvirt.connect_via_ssh = false
    libvirt.username = "root"
    libvirt.storage_pool_name = "data"
  end
end
```

On RHEL 6.4 I get the following error

```
Error while connecting to libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu://localhost/system?no_verify=1:
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Unable to import client certificate /etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem
```

I tried to setup the cert like described here http://libvirt.org/remote.html#Remote_TLS_CA but this didnt change anything.

If i try to connect via ssh vagrant is able to slowly upload the box but afterwards I get the next failure

```
Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: internal error Process exited while reading console log output: char device redirected to /dev/pts/20
qemu-kvm: -drive file=/local/data/virtualbox/root_1372773363.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qcow2: could not open disk image /local/data/virtualbox/root_1372773363.img: Invalid argument
```

On Fedora 17 or Arch Linux I cannot even install the vagrant-libvirt plugin, because it cannot find the libvirt library (lying under /usr/lib).

Does someone somehow manage to get vagrant working with libvirt or is the libvirt plugin still to alpha?

TIA && have a nice day!

Basti

Comment: I hit the same issue, it's due to secure booting and signing issue. follow the link below if you are using version Ubuntu 20.04, virtualbox 6.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248315/sign-virtual-box-modules-vboxdrv-vboxnetflt-vboxnetadp-vboxpci-centos-8,

Answer (score 8):

I got this `Error while connecting to libvirt` error but it was because I was running `vagrant up` without specifying the `provider`.

In my case I needed

```
$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while trying to start a Vagrant machine up, without having Virtualbox initially installed (although I had previously written I needed it).

Installing Virtualbox fixed this issue right away.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this same issue. To fix it I had to essentially follow this guide : http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TLSSetup

Note that the guide has multiple steps and it is LONG. Its not an "easy" fix though once you have the CAcert/key HostCert/key and ClientCert/key all in place, with the correct permissions and the correct ownership, everything works as expected.

thanks for reporting this and I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error on a pretty much fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10.

When I did: `vagrant up --provider virtualbox`

I got this error message

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
that is not supported by this version of Vagrant. Please install one of
the supported versions listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 6.0

A Vagrant update may also be available that adds support for the version
you specified. Please check www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html to download
the latest version
```

So this helped in my case: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0`

Answer (score 0):

both virtual box and vagrant have to be up to date or at least compatible versions so uninstall and re install both programs (to make sure they are compatible install the most up to date version of both programs), note that vagrant has to be installed after virtual box